# Blocking Someone On Twitter: Do I show up on timeline?

Tags: twitter

If I have blocked someone on Twitter, but they follow people I follow and people that follow me, if our shared followers retweet one of my tweets, do they see that? 
Also, if a shared follower mentions me in a tweet, will my name appear in that tweet?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1: If our shared followers re-tweet one of my tweets, do they see that?**

No, your tweets are not appeared the blocked person's timeline. However the tweets are visible to the blocked person by viewing the shared person's timeline.

**Question 2:  If a shared follower mentions me in a tweet, will my name appear in that tweet?**

Yes, if the shared person mentioned your name in his/her tweet, your name will appear in the blocked person's time line.